# I am using Saxon 9.5 HE for testing . Could anyone please suggest me an example to use integrated extension functions to call a java method

Tags: xslt-2.0, saxon

I'm having a problem to find a quite good example for Integrated
extension functions case.
I need to call a method in java class from XSL, but until now i can't find the same
example for my class. It would be great help if someone can suggest a example for such a scenario.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the source for the EXPath ZIP file module for real life examples. For example any of the files in:

https://dev.saxonica.com/repos/archive/opensource/latest9.5/hej/net/sf/saxon/option/expath/zip/functions/